# Node.js Buffer() is crashing my program for some reason

Tags: node.js, canvas, buffer

I'm trying to get an image from a URL and load it into canvas using node.js. My code gets to the point where I convert the stream into a Buffer, then exits. No errors, no warnings, just exits. Does anyone know why this might be?

```
bkurl = 'some_url'
const response = await fetch(bkurl);
response.arrayBuffer().then(async (data) => {

    //This prints
    console.log(Buffer(data));

    const background = new CanvasImport.Image();
    background.src = Buffer(data);
    
    //This does not
    console.log(background.src)

    context.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Comment: Do you realize that using `Buffer(...)` is inappropriate.  You can use `Buffer.from(...)` if you want.  I don't know if this has anything at all to do with your issue - probably not.  But, if the data is already a buffer or an ArrayBuffer, it's unclear why you're trying to wrap it in another buffer.

Comment: Which NPM module are you using for Canvas?  I'm specifically looking for the documentation for `CanvasImport.Image()`.

Comment: I'm using ```require('@napi-rs/canvas');```. As for the constructor, I realize that was a dumb way of doing it and have changed it to ```Buffer.from()```, unfortunately the error stayed the same

Comment: I can't find any doc that would cover this line of code: `background.src = Buffer(data);`.  It seems likely that you're not doing this correctly and the native code in the canvas implementation crashes.  Also, this is on the NPM page: *This project is in pre-release stage. And there may some bugs existed.*.

Comment: The project worked just fine with a local file, but it just refuses to work with a remote one. I think you might be right about the bugs though

Comment: Then, you're apparently doing something different with the data from the remote file and not presenting it in the exact same format. Or the data coming from the remote source is wrong.